# Implementing search in MEAN stack application

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, elasticsearch, search

I am new to MEAN stack application domain & wondering how to implement search in my MEAN stack application. Though I have searched for it but the solutions do suggest using elastic search. Pls suggest if its a good idea to use elastic search engine or custom building one for my app

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends how much data you expect in search? If its a huge amount of data then go with Elastic search, its light weight and faster. If you have very basic search functionality, you can implement normal search with onChange. If you have very least data, bring the data once and apply filter on Front end side directly.